# JavaScript - beforeunload override on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following script on my page to help users stop closing the window accidentally and to notify them if they're navigating away from the page.

```
<script>$(window).on( 'beforeunload.edit-post', function() {return true;});</script>
```

However, when a user submits a form on my page, I don't want this pop up to trigger. I tried adding `.preventDefault();` to it but it didn't work. How do I make it so the `beforeunload` pop up doesn't appear when the user submits the form with the button?

```
<script>

function submit() {
    $(window).on('beforeunload.edit-post').preventDefault();
    $("#form").submit();
}

</script>

<form id="form"><input name="example" value="example"></form>

<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The `on()` method does not return an event for you to prevent.  The `on()` sets up an event handler to handle future events.  You need to provide a callback as the event handler that conditionally prevents the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit()` function should remove the `beforeunload` listener.

```
function submit() {
    $(window).off('beforeunload.edit-post');
}
```

It doesn't need to call `$("#form").submit()`, that happens by default unless it calls `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Barmar!!!!!!!! Fourth time you've helped me with an answer here on StackOverflow. Thank you!!